# Powershell Array or Hash Table?

Tags: powershell, hash

This seems to be an area where I am lacking. I have written this script that would add users to 1 group if they are not in any of the other 3 and only if they have an Exchange GUID, but it is slow as usual, due to the calls back and forth to AD. I have tried various attempts at using hash tables, but I am not able to figure out how to get sub-string properties like MemberOf from the keys. I see the advantage of gathering up the data first via `$hash = @{}` but my various tests always come up null because I don't understand how to get strings out of it. Here's what I have after trying to put it back to the old working version... Thx

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $a = Get-Date
    $Logs = "C:\scripts\SEC-E2010TierGroup3\SEC-E2010TierGroup3-additions_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
    $Grp0 = "SEC-E2010TierGroup0"
    $Grp1 = "SEC-E2010TierGroup1"
    $Grp2 = "SEC-E2010TierGroup2"
    $Grp3 = "SEC-E2010TierGroup3"
    #$ADUserTable = @{}

 $Users = Get-ADUser -server "dc114" -LdapFilter "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!objectClass=inetOrgPerson))(sAMAccountName=s0*)(!sAMAccountName=*-d)(!sAMAccountName=*-e)(!sAMAccountName=*-a)(!Name=Test*)(!Name=v-*)(!employeeID=\00))" -properties SamAccountName, DistinguishedName,Name, memberof, msExchMailboxGuid
    <#ForEach-Object {
        $ADUserTable[$_.SamAccountName] = $_
    }#>

    function Get-GroupMembership($DN,$group){
        $objEntry = [adsi]("LDAP://"+$DN)
        $objEntry.memberOf | where { $_ -match $group}
    }
        #Usage: 
         # Get-GroupMembership "DistinguishedName" "DomainAdmins"#>

    <#$Active = #>ForEach ($user in $Users) {

    $strName = $User.samaccountname
    $DNUser = $User.distinguishedname

    $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$strName))"
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
    $objUser = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $Exch = $objUser.msExchMailboxGuid#>

    #If here, has an Exchange Mailbox.(Get-GroupMembership "$UserDN" "$Grp0")
    if ($Exch.count -eq 1){  

            If (Get-GroupMembership "$DNUser" "$Grp0") {(""+ $a +" [" + $User + "], User:[" + $User.value.Name + "] in SEC-E2010TierGroup0.") | Out-File -FilePath $Logs -Append
                            Continue}

                If (Get-GroupMembership "$DNUser" "$Grp1") {(""+ $a +" [" + $User + "], User:[" + $User.value.Name + "] in SEC-E2010TierGroup1.") | Out-File -FilePath $Logs -Append
                            Continue}

                    If (Get-GroupMembership "$DNUser" "$Grp2") {(""+ $a +" [" + $User + "], User:[" + $User.value.Name + "] in SEC-E2010TierGroup2.") | Out-File -FilePath $Logs -Append
                            Continue}

                        If (!(Get-GroupMembership "$DNUser" "$Grp3")) {

                        (""+ $a +" [" + $User + "], User:[" + $User.value.Name + "] not in SEC-E2010TierGroup3. Adding to group3.") | Out-File -FilePath $Logs -Append}

        }

    #If here, no Exch Mailbox.
    if ($Exch.count -eq 1) {(""+ $a +" [" + $User + "], User:[" + $User.value.Name + "] does not have Exchange GUID.") | Out-File -FilePath $Logs -Append
    continue}

    } #$Active | Export-csv C:\Scripts\SEC-E2010TierGroup3\SEC-E2010TIER-Pre-Implimentation-rpt_2-18-2016.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: There was a smart quote in the code. I replaced it with a regular double quote to satisfy Google Prettify.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really go through this and rewrite the whole thing but I can give some general advice.

When it comes to calling cmdlets take advantage of the pipeline. Typically a cmdlet knows how to handle multiple items in the most efficient way. When each cmdlet call has overhead, like when calling AD cmdlets and *especially* Exchange cmdlets, this effect will be magnified. For example:

```
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mailbox $_
}
```

vs:

```
$users | Get-Mailbox
```

The overhead of connecting to exchange is repeated *per user* in the first call, but only happens once in the second scenario.

So when possible, make the fewest calls to remote cmdlets you can, build collections that satisfy the pipeline requirements to future remote cmdlets, and pipe them in. Even if it seems to require more finagling, it will run much faster.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. So, I'm assuming I can say $HasMail = $Users | Get-Mailbox and test true or false instead of the directory searcher method?

Comment: @MarcGel possibly yeah, maybe add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Comment: Although a nice tip, I was hoping to learn more about how to use a hash table here. I'm able to create one and can see the values in there, but I don't seem to be able to run string comparisons like I can with an array.

Comment: @MarcGel I'm afraid I don't really understand your question. I'm not seeing in the code where you're trying to create or use a hashtable and I'm unclear what purpose you think one would serve. Maybe edit your question with a more concise example of what you're trying to achieve with a hashtable and what isn't working?